# Windows batch file fails to locate files

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

Below is a short batch file.

```
if exist ("help/user/Content/build.xml") ( echo file exists) ELSE (echo File Deleted)
if exist ("archibus.war") (echo File not deleted!) ELSE (echo File Deleted)
if exist ("build.xml") ( echo file exists) ELSE (echo File Deleted)
```

The files are never found even when they actually exist. Am I not specifying the paths correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paths are ok. Just remove the `(` and `)` on the file names:

```
if exist "help/user/Content/build.xml" ( echo file exists) ELSE (echo File Deleted)
if exist "archibus.war" (echo File not deleted!) ELSE (echo File Deleted)
if exist "build.xml" ( echo file exists) ELSE (echo File Deleted)
```